# Swap Content Layout in a Loop Using Smarty

Tags: php, layout, smarty, cmsmadesimple

I'm using CMSMS which uses smarty. I need to show the content of the News Module in an odd/even order. I've tried using {cycle} and {section} but I'm not a programmer so I'm just guessing here.
[Layout Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StfsF.png)

The sample code for each layout is something like this:

```
<!-- Layout A -->
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-center">
            <div class="image">
                Image
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="text">
                Text Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Layout B -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="text">
                Text Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-center">
            <div class="image">
                Image
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have several news and they should be presented like this:

1. Layout A
2. Layout B
3. Layout A
4. Layout B
5. And so on...

Is this possible using smarty?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CMSms version uses Smarty 3 use

```
     {foreach $myNames as $name}
       {if $name@iteration is div by 2}
         <!-- Layout B -->
       {else}
         <!__ Layout A -->
       {/if}
     {/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution kind of worked, because it is rendering only "Layout A". What I see is that the {foreach} needed to get the content looks like this {foreach from=$items item=entry}. So I'm assuming that the {if $name@iteration is div by 2} should be different. Am I right? :D

Comment: Yes that was a generic thing. Change $name to $entry and $myNames to items